# Zend_PDF text formatting

Tags: php, text, formatting, zend-pdf

I use Zend Framework for my project. And my question is how can I convert html text like "**hello***world*" into PDF text to be the same using Zend_PDF ?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

i think there is no automatic convert function like html2pdf. You can set the Font like this :

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_COURIER_BOLD);
$pdfPage->setFont($font, 36) // font and size
        ->drawText('hello', 72, 720, 'UTF-8')
        ->drawText('world', 72, 650, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Hmm , it works ,but there is a new problem. I have different spacing between words. When words have different length they also have different spacing between them because font is not monospaced. How can I workaround this ?

Comment: Don't mind I found the solution in the internet 
public function getTextWidth($text, Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font $font, $font_size) 
{
 $drawing_text = iconv('', 'UTF-16BE', $text);
 $characters    = array();
 for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($drawing_text); $i++) {
  $characters[] = (ord($drawing_text[$i++]) << 8) | ord ($drawing_text[$i]);
 }
 $glyphs        = $font->glyphNumbersForCharacters($characters);
 $widths        = $font->widthsForGlyphs($glyphs);
 $text_width   = (array_sum($widths) / $font->getUnitsPerEm()) * $font_size;
 return $text_width; 
}